# Calling an instance of a stateless class's build vs a stateful class's build

Tags: dart, flutter

I have noticed a difference when calling a stateful class compared to a stateless one.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App Title',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: "Title"
          ),
          body: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 300.0,
              child: ItemListState()._buildItemsList(),
            )
          ],
        )),
    );
  }
}
```

In the example above if the class is stateful(`ItemListState()`) I need to call `ItemListState().buildItemsList()` (the method returns a ListView I have built.)

If the class is stateless I can just call `ItemListState()`(the build method returns the same ListView)

Why is it acceptable to use what's returned from build from the stateless class but not the stateful one. I suspect it's because the framework cannot be sure when to call build or something similar.

The get an error when trying to use the build function of the stateful class to return my listView `The argument type 'ItemListState' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'`

Comment: what is the question? what do you want to build?

Comment: There is normally no need to use the result of `build()`. `build()` is supposed to be called from Flutter, not from your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference when you call `Stateful` or `Stateless` Widget , both classes have `build` method so in both cases you have to use the constructor of the Stateful or Stateless not the constructor of the `State` class.

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Material App Title',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: "Title"
            ),
            body: ListView(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 300.0,
                child: ItemList(),
              )
            ],
          )),
      );
    }
  }
```

If you are using `Stateful`

```
    class ItemList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      ItemListState createState() => ItemListState();
    }

    class ItemListState extends State<ItemList> {

      _buildItemsList(){
        return Container();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return _buildItemsList();
      }
    }
```

If you are using `Stateless`

```
  class ItemList extends StatelessWidget {
   _buildItemsList(){
      return Container();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return _buildItemsList();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Very deductive of you to figure out what I was doing without seeing the code. You are mentioning constructors. I read that the constructors are implicit when they are not defined. Do you know what they would currently look like if they were defined. That is I don't see how the constructors are impacting if I make the call from the ItemListState or ItemList. I understand now "it's a thing" but not why

Comment: if you need pass parameters to your stateful/stateless classes you will need to define your constructor with the custom params

Comment: What I am saying is I don't understand why you need to use ItemList's constructor and not able to use ItemListState constructor. If I understand override correctly it's overriding the build class for use in ItemListState. It's not overriding the superclasses build.

Comment: I think you can, but what is the result type of _buildItemsList() method? Also i noticed that you are trying to call a private method. That is not possible

Comment: The result type? as in what is it returning, it's returning a ListView. It's type is Widget. It worked when I called the private method